# Creating a Mixed Mode C++ Bridge from C to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, mixed-mode

I hope someone can help me with this, I'm mostly a C# developer so my
C and C++ skills are bad.  I have a native C dll that is a plugin of a
larger application.  I cross compile this dll for windows on linux
using gcc.

In the native dll when I create a D3DSurface I want to call a function
in a Mixed Mode C++ dll and pass in the pointer to the surface along
with a Hwnd/handle.  That Mixed Mode C++ should then call my C#
managed code.

As an example, in C I want to do the following;

```
Hwnd handle;
LPDIRECT3DSURFACE d3dtarg;
SurfaceCreated(handle, d3dtarg);
```

In C# I want this called from the mixed mode assembly

```
public static class D3DInterop
{
    public static void SurfaceCreated(IntPtr handle, IntPtr surface)
    {
        //do work
    }
}
```

Since I suck at C++, I just want to know if someone can give me an
example of what I need to code for the mixed mode dll.  I'd also like
to not have to compile the mixed mode dll with directx headers, so is
there a way I can cast the 'C' LPDIRECT3DSURFACE into a generic
pointer?  In C# I just use the IntPtr anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Create a managed C++ (C++/CLI) DLL project which will be callable from C and will also be able to reference other .Net assemblies (namely your C# thing). Then all your C++/CLI bridge would have to do is translate the data types from HWND to IntPtr, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [Microsoft XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA)? It supposedly has managed wrappers for DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `void *` in the mixed-mode DLL. There is an implicit cast from a pointer to anything (including a pointer to `IDirect3DSurface`) to `void *`. You can then cast that pointer to `IntPtr`.