# std::string in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I thought the problem is inside my C++ function,but I tried this

C++ Function in C++ dll:

```
bool __declspec( dllexport ) OpenA(std::string file)
{
return true;
}
```

C# code:

```
[DllImport("pk2.dll")]
public static extern bool OpenA(string path);

    if (OpenA(@"E:\asdasd\"))
```

I get an exception that the memory is corrupt,why?

If I remove the std::string parameter,it works great,but with std::string it doesnt work.

Comment: Maybe you can solve it by making a managed c++ bridge that unpacks the string? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267057/creating-a-mixed-mode-c-bridge-from-c-to-c) is a SO question about this subject.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

std::string and c# string are not compatible with each other. As far as I know the c# string corresponds to passing `char*` or `wchar_t*` in c++ as far as interop is concerned.
One of the reasons for this is that There can be many different implementations to std::string and c# can't assume that you're using any particular one.

Comment: Not to mention that std::string is also a template, which opens another interesting can of worms for the interop.

Comment: The most proper way is to use char* and create std::string from it. If you want to return a std::string to C#, you must allocate a char* with CoTaskMemAlloc with size of std::string's size()+1, then memcpy std::string's data() into this buffer and return it. Easy. Note: you MUST use CoTaskMemAlloc!

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
bool __declspec( dllexport ) OpenA(const TCHAR* pFile)
{ 
   std::string filename(pFile);
   ...
   return true;
}
```

You should also specify the appropriate character set (unicode/ansi) in your DllImport attribute.

As an aside, unrelated to your marshalling problem, one would normally pass a std:string as a const reference:  const std:string& filename.

Comment: that std::string will fail compilation if _UNICODE is defined. might be better to do an #ifdef and use std::wstring or simply make a typedef for a tstring depending on _UNICODE.

Answer (score 2):

std::wstring and System.string can be compatible through below conversion:

C++ :

```
bool func(std::wstring str, int number)
{
  BSTR tmp_str = SysAllocStringLen(str.c_str(), str.size());
  VARIANT_BOOL ret = VARIANT_FALSE;

  // call c# COM DLL
  ptr->my_com_function(tmp_str, number, &ret);

  SysFreeString(tmp_str);

  return (ret != VARIANT_FALSE) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to marshal a C++ std::string in the way you are attempting.  What you really need to do here is write a wrapper function which uses a plain old `const char*` and converts to a std::string under the hood.

C++

```
extern C { 
  void OpenWrapper(const WCHAR* pName) {
    std::string name = pName;
    OpenA(name);
  }
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("pk2.dll")]
public static extern void OpenWrapper( [In] string name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is a tad old but for future googlers, this should also work (without using char* in C++)

C#:

```
public static extern bool OpenA([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] path);
```

C++:

```
bool __declspec( dllexport ) OpenA(std::string file);
```

Comment: What do you mean? Did you try the code above and it didn't work?

Comment: I mean, is there any reference page which states that it should work, and defines requirements for it to work?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find the reference for this atm (this was quite a long time ago). However you could try this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx