# How to pass a string from C++-CLI to C# via C++-CLI callbacks and delegates

Tags: c#, visual-c++, callback, c++-cli, interop

I have a C++-CLR wrapper around a standard C++ library called from C#.  To receive status messages from the library I use a delegate assigned to a callback in the C++ code via Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate.

This has taken me quite some time to get working and I'm very, very close (I think).  The C# delegate is called but the string isn't passed correctly across the boundary.

When I call TakesCallback("Test String") from the C++ code I just get rubbish back in the C# function.

--- The original C++ class and callback function ---

```
class Solver
{
    private:

    std::string TakesCallback(const std::string message) 
    {
        return cb(message);
    }

    public:

    // Declare an unmanaged function type that takes a string
    typedef std::string (__stdcall* ANSWERCB)(const std::string);
    ANSWERCB cb;
};
```

--- Function to set the callback from the managed wrapper ----

```
// Set the delegate callback
void ManagedSolver::SetMessageCallback(SendMessageDelegate^ sendMessageDelegate)
{
    _sendMessage = sendMessageDelegate;

    // Use GetFunctionPointerForDelegate to get the pointer for delegate callback
    IntPtr ip = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(sendMessageDelegate);
    _solver->cb = static_cast<Solver::ANSWERCB>(ip.ToPointer());
}
```

--- C# function passed to the C++ \ CLR wrapper SetMessageCallBack ----

```
private void Message(string message)
{
    XtraMessageBox.Show(message, "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean Managed C++? Managed Extensions for C++ stopped being supported in (I think) Visual Studio 2003. C++/CLI is it's replacement, and it's a completely different language...

Comment: Hi Billy, sorry you're right of course.  My wrapper is C++ / CLR around a standard C++ library.  I've updated the title and body.

Comment: OK I've solved it std::string won't work with interop due to the variety of implementations as stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874551/stdstring-in-c  I'll come back and answer this as soon as StackOverflow allows me to.

Comment: Pass message.c_str() instead, compatible with the default marshaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ `std::string` and .NET `System::String` are not interchangeable.  C# cannot use the first, and native C++ code cannot use the second.  What you need is a C++/CLI function that accepts `std::string` and converts it to `System::String^` before calling the delegate.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using [the code from this page](http://www.nuclex.org/articles/5-cxx/10-marshaling-strings-in-cxx-cli) for some months now and I find it very good. It is only one header file you can copy across your projects and it does the job quickly and cleanly.

You use for instance

```
std::wstring s = clix::marshalString<E_UNICODE>(myCliString);
```

or

```
System::String^ s = clix::marshalString<E_ANSI>(mystdstring);
```

it works both ways and let you specify what encoding you want (ANSI, UTF8 or Windows's unicode -- actually UTF16).

Answer (score 1):

In general, std c++ classes cannot be marshaled to/from C#. If you are building your C++ code as Unicode, I would recommend to change your code into the following:

C++

```
// Declare an unmanaged function type that takes a string
typedef int (__stdcall* ANSWERCB)(LPCTSTR);
```

C#

```
private void Message([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string message)
{
    XtraMessageBox.Show(message, "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

Take a look at the following [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7esfatk4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

C++ (Unmanaged)

```
class DllContext
{
public:
typedef void (__stdcall *LOG_CALLBECK)(const wchar_t* LogString);
DllContext(LOG_CALLBECK WriteLog) // Constructor
{
    this->WriteLog = WriteLog;
    this->WriteLog(L"Creating сontext..."); // UNICODE string!
}

private:
LOG_CALLBECK WriteLog;
}

// Export function
SENDAUDIOCLIENT_API DllContext *CreateContext(DllContext::LOG_CALLBECK WriteLog)
{
    return new DllContext(WriteLog);
}
```

C#

```
class MyClass
{
private delegate void WriteLog_Delegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string Mess);
private WriteLog_Delegate WriteLog;

[DllImport("My.dll", EntryPoint = "?CreateContext@@YAPAVDllContext@@P6GXPB_W@Z@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateContext(WriteLog_Delegate WriteLogProc);

private IntPtr Context = IntPtr.Zero;

public MyClass()
{
    this.WriteLog = new WriteLog_Delegate(this.WriteLogToConsole);
        this.Context = CreateContext(this.WriteLog);
}

private void WriteLogToConsole(string Mess)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message from unmanaged code: {0}", Mess);
}
}
```