# dllimport from c++ to c# type dismatch

Tags: c#, c++

i am not sure what the problem is.  i have a c++ function returning a string as follows

```
extern "C++" __declspec(dllexport) std::string D()
{
    return "say hello";
}
```

and on my c#

```
[DllImport("MyMSG.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern string D();
```

when i run the wpf, i get an

```
'Unable to find an entry point named 'D' in DLL 'MyMSG.dll'.'
```

error.  it seems to me that c++ and c# have a type mismatch on strings?  i tried with other types like int and bool and i didnt get any problem.  can someone explain please?  thank you

EDIT
first i would like to thank dxiv and andy for the response.  i did more research and found that changing

```
public static extern string D();
```

to

```
public static extern System.IntPtr D();
```

then calling

```
string x = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(D());
```

seems to give me the right value.

Comment: The C++ `std::string` and .NET `System.String` (which the C# `string` is aliased to) are completely different, unrelated types. You cannot use standard C++ library types like `std::string` in APIs used from managed code.

Comment: Look at how the Win32 API does strings. For example [GetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta). The calling application will allocate memory on the stack or heap, then pass the pointer to the DLL which will then copy the data over to that pointer.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with a string.  Read error message : "Unable to find an entry point named 'D' in DLL 'MyMSG.dll".  I do not thing the latest version of the MyMSG.dll file is in the bin folder of the project or you are using the wrong bin folder (debug/release).  Right click the MyMSG.dll in the solution explorer of project and check the location of where the file is located.  Should be the debug folder of c++ project.

Comment: `seems to give me the right value` - it only seems that way. You are leaking memory by creating `std:string`s that are not going to be destructed.

Comment: @jdweng, i tried adding another function that returns like a bool or int. it works without any error.  Only happens when I have string.  I just cleaned the solution and build it again. 
 I copied MyMSG.dll from debug folder of c++ project  to the debug folder of my c# project.  is that the right way to do?

Comment: @GSerg,  doesn't c# does the clean up?  any suggestion on the right path?

Comment: @Jim C# cannot know how to call the destructor of an unmanaged object. You [cannot even](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15146682/11683) pass `std::string` between unmanaged modules of different versions.

Comment: A string in c# is a class object while a string in c++ is an array of btyes terminated with a '\0'.