# Use C++ class in C# with strings (Dll)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, c++-cli

I am trying to use my C++ class in my C# program. So I made a .dll-file to use it in C#. My problem is, that I am working with strings. My question is: How can I return a std::string to my C# program?

My C++ class (header-file):

```
using namespace std;

class CComPort
{
public:     
    string ReadLine();          
    void WriteLine(string userInput);
};
```

My dll code:

```
string CppWrapper::CComPortWrapper::ReadLineWrapper()
{
    return comPort->ReadLine();
}

void CppWrapper::CComPortWrapper::WriteLineWrapper(string userInput)
{
    comPort->WriteLine(userInput);
}
```

My C#-Code:

```
comPort.WriteLineWrapper(tb_send.Text);
```

Error:

```
'CComPortWrapper.WriteLineWrapper(?,?)' is not supported by the language.
```

I tried to change the dll file to something like this, but it didn't worked:

```
void CppWrapper::CComPortWrapper::WriteLineWrapper(String ^ userInput)
{
    comPort->WriteLine(userInput);
}
```

What is the rigth way to change it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874551/stdstring-in-c)

Comment: std::string is not supported by the C# language.  We can't tell what type your ComPort::WriteLine() function needs, but Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi() tends to fit.  Don't forget Marshal::FreeHGlobal().  Paying attention to the exact encoding never hurts either, consider declaring it `void WriteLine(array<Byte>^ buffer);` and use `pin_ptr` so the C# code has a shot at getting it right with the Encoding class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're wrapping a class used just for serial port communication. There are ways of accessing the serial port directly from C#, without needing C++/CLI. Unless there's a lot of logic in the C++ class that cannot be ported/would be hard to port to C#, please do consider doing the serial communication in C#.

---

You haven't shown us the declaration of your `CComPortWrapper` class. I'm assuming that it's `public ref class CComPortWrapper`.

If the goal of your wrapper is to make it callable from managed languages (e.g., C#), then you should use managed types in your declaration.

In this case, you should declare the methods of `CComPortWrapper` to take & return [`System::String^`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx?cs-lang=cpp). Within the wrapper, convert it to/from `std::string`, and call the unmanaged class with that.

I recommend using [`marshal_as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/marshal-as) to do the conversion, especially since you're converting from one class to another. You don't need to deal with explicitly allocating memory or anything like that; let each string class manage its own memory, and let `marshal_as` deal with copying & converting the data.

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;

String^ CppWrapper::CComPortWrapper::ReadLineWrapper()
{
    std::string result = comPort->ReadLine();
    return marshal_as<String^>(result);
}

void CppWrapper::CComPortWrapper::WriteLineWrapper(String^ userInput)
{
    std::string input = marshal_as<std::string>(userInput);
    comPort->WriteLine(input);
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error with your code: "'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type,false>::marshal_as': This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file needed for this conversion is not included.  Please refer to the documentation on 'How to: Extend the Marshaling Library' for adding your own marshaling method."

Comment: And yes it is 'public ref class CComPortWrapper'

Comment: @User987123 make sure you have the proper include. See edit.