# Lifetime of a temporary

Tags: c++, pinvoke

I am encountering some sporadic crashes when calling into a C++ library (not under my control)  from C#.

The internal code of the C++ library is roughly like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Holder {
    public:
    static std::shared_ptr<Holder> create() {
        return std::make_shared<Holder>();
    }

    const std::string& getRef() {
        return value;
    }

    private:
    std::string value;
};

extern "C" void getRef(std::string& v) {
    auto h = Holder::create();
    v = h->getRef();
}
```

`getRef` is called from C# via P/invoke with no special marshalling.

Is this guaranteed to work? `h` goes out of scope at the end of `getRef`, but a reference to its member `value` is held and passed on. Is this reference still valid when being access on the C# side?

Comment: I'm not convinced it's safe to call your `getRef` except from proc C++ code, as it accepts a `std::string&` as an argument - .NET marshalling only supports raw `char*`-style strings or COM strings. For one thing, C# Strings/Char are always 16-bit, but `std::string` will use 8-bits - otherwise you'd use `std::wstring`...

Comment: For strings, see [Default marshalling of strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-for-strings). See also possible duplicate: [std::string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874551/stdstring-in-c)

Comment: And the function can't be rewritten to take a `char*` pointing at `std::string::c_str()` from the local variable either, because then the pointer will be pointing at a local object going out of scope for sure. So maybe a wrapper function is the way to go here.

Comment: For all of its faults, [swig](https://www.swig.org/) makes something like this really easy.

Comment: `extern "C" void getRef(std::string& v)` -- You should not be using reference parameters for functions that are going to be called from non-C++ environments.  A reference can be implemented in whatever way the C++ compiler has implemented them -- there is no requirement for a reference to be implemented as a pointer (the C++ standard makes no mention of how references are implemented internally).  Thus only C++ applications compiled by the same C++ compiler can utilize this function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But then you shouldn't even use a std::string there in the first place, reference or not. Different C++-compilers have different std-implementations, and trying to copy to an std::string that was compiled with a different compiler is very unlikely to suceed.

Comment: @Juliean -- Yes, I was going to add that as a comment.  You shouldn't use `std::string` there either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ part is fine.

`v = h->getRef();`

`getRef` returns a reference to a string that will be valid until `h` is killed off, which happens at the end of the function. However, the string is **copied into the `v` string** in this line, so no problem.

> h goes out of scope at the end of getRef, but a reference to its member value is held and passed on.

That's where you are wrong; that reference is not passed on to anything.

---

EDIT: concerning the comments that this doesn't copy anything, try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const std::string& getRef()
{
    static const std::string result("success!");
    return result;
}

void test(std::string& v)
{
    v=getRef();
}

int main()
{
    std::string string="failure!";
    test(string);
    std::cout << string << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp; ./a.out
success!
```

Basically, while a reference is functionally similar to a pointer, it can't be assigned to: if you assign to a reference, you're always assigning to the object that's being referenced.

Comment: Uh right, my C++ is rusty as can be. Still this is fishy code and returning the string by value would be the clearest.

Comment: @Lundin well, he says it's called from C# -- I don't know much about C#, but inter-language calling gateways often have rather limited abilities. Maybe he can only return stuff like that.